# How to undo Response.Cache.SetNoStore()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iis, cache-control

I've a CMS application code which calls `Response.Cache.SetNoStore()` on all request and if i'm correct, this will be prevents proxies/cdn to cache those pages/content. Therefore, i'm conditionally calling the below code:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

But this doesn't take out the no-store param from the response header, this is the returned http header:

```
Cache-Control:public, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=1800
```

Therefore my question is, how can i take out the nostore param pragmatically? If this isn't possible, how/where can i parse/modify the http-header, because i tried to parsed on PagePreRender event and the nostore param hasn't been applied...which leads to wonder at which life cycle is this appended to the header?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to undo `SetNoStore` once you call it. You need to use some creative routing to process the request in a different way or reflection to invoke the built-in reset that is private.

You can get access to [`HttpCachePolicyWrapper`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Abstractions/HttpCachePolicyWrapper.cs) to access the underlying [`HttpCachePolicy`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpCachePolicy.cs), then assign the internal `NoStore` field or issue `Reset` to revert to the default cache policy.

```cs
response.Cache.SetNoStore(); // assign no-store
BindingFlags hiddenItems = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
var httpCachePolicyWrapper = response.Cache.GetType(); // HttpCachePolicyWrapper type

var httpCache = httpCachePolicyWrapper.InvokeMember("_httpCachePolicy", BindingFlags.GetField | hiddenItems, null, response.Cache, null);
var httpCachePolicy = httpCache.GetType(); // HttpCachePolicy type

// Reset Cache Policy to Default    
httpCachePolicy.InvokeMember("Reset", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | hiddenItems, null, httpCache, null);
var resetAllCachePolicy = httpCachePolicy.InvokeMember("_noStore", BindingFlags.GetField | hiddenItems, null, httpCache, null);

response.Cache.SetNoStore(); // assign no-store

// Undo SetNoStore Cache Policy
httpCachePolicy.InvokeMember("_noStore", BindingFlags.SetField | hiddenItems, null, httpCache, new object[] { false });
var resetNoStoreOnly = httpCachePolicy.InvokeMember("_noStore", BindingFlags.GetField | hiddenItems, null, httpCache, null);
```