# Why is cache-control header set to private even when I set it to a different value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, http-headers, cache-control, .net-4.8

I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 with MVC and trying to set HttpResponseMessage's cacheControl header to `public, max-age=300`. My Approach is the following

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var resp = new HtpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent { ...};
        };


        resp.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        };

        return resp
    }
```

However, the cache-control header of the response is always `Cache-Control: private`. Why is this happening? Is IIS overwriting it or something? I want to apply this change only for this action method.

I have also tried using `[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]` but it did not help.

I have researched this, and I have found related questions such as

- [IIS/ASP.NET responds with cache-control: private for all requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224561/iis-asp-net-responds-with-cache-control-private-for-all-requests)
- [Override ASP.NET cache policy and set Cache-Control to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825727/override-asp-net-cache-policy-and-set-cache-control-to-public)

But none of it really worked for my issue. Could someone please give me advice on how to fix this?